# Reversing elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, element

I've been looking at a for-loop that reverses the elements in an array, but I do not quite understand what's going on inside it. This is the code:

```
 int middleIndex = (array.length) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < middleIndex; i++) {
        int temporaryVariable = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = temporaryVariable;
    }
```

What exactly does the two lines below int temporaryVariable = array[i] do? How exactly does it reverse the elements?

Comment: take a debugger and / or a piece of paper and work it out, should take you at most 5 minutes and is far better than asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remember that array indexes start from 0.
So the index of the last element is the `array.length - 1`.

Those 3 lines are swapping the first item with the last item, then the 2nd item with the 2nd-from-last item, etc. The `temporaryVariable` is used as a temporary place to store one of the values during swapping, so that it doesn't get lost when it is overwritten by the other value.

1. Take a copy of the value at `i`:

   `int temporaryVariable = array[i];`
2. Put item `i` from the end of the array (`array.length - 1 - i`) instead of it.

   `array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];`
3. Put the temporarily stored item which was item `i` at `i` from the end (`array.length - 1 - i`).

   `array[array.length - 1 - i] = temporaryVariable;`

The loop stops when `i` reaches the middle of the array. (If the array has an odd number of elements the middle one stays where it is.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it.

Answer (score 1):

It effectively reverses the elements of the array by swapping `first` with `last` element, `second` with `second_last` etc. In this way the number of operations are `ayrray_length / 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 lines after `int temporaryVariable = array[i];` simply swap the i'th element with the i'th from last element, and we run this loop half time the number of elements in array.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is taking N/2 iterations of swapping values stored in an array. It starts from the beggining of the array (Index 0) and goes until its half(index N/2). It swaps the first element(indexed 0) with the last one (indexed N - 1 - 0), then swaps the second element(indexed 0 + 1) with the one before the last one(indexed N - 1 - (0 + 1)), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

another part was to return the second biggest number, but for some reason it returns the third biggest number, which is really weird.

This is the code:

```
public static int returnSecondBiggest(int[] array) {
int largestElement = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largestElement) {
        largestElement = array[i];
    }
}

int secondBiggest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > secondBiggest && array[i] != largestElement) {
        secondBiggest = array[i];
    }
}

return secondBiggest;
```

}

How does it return the third when the code should return the second? I'm so lost.